# Having problem connecting to my Express server from another machine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I am developing a Node.js Chess application with Express.
I can't manage to connect to my Express server im running on my pc with another machine which is connected to the same Wifi network as my pc.

I have tried the following:

1. listening on the default address , on '0.0.0.0' and on my pc IP address.
2. listening on different ports, like 3000 and 80.
3. enabling a port rule in the Firewall.

this is the code in app.js :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("chess_game"));

app.get('/' , (req , res) => {
   console.log("get request")
   res.sendFile('./chess_game/index.html')
})

app.listen(80 ,'192.168.137.1' ,() =>   
console.log("listening..."));
```

Nothing seems to make a difference, any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest that you share the relevant code, otherwise is impossible to find out what the problem can be

Comment: Some extra information you could provide, in hopes that someone can help you: (1) What OS are you running on both computers? (2) Did you check if you have the firewall setup correctly? Do you have a rule to allow traffic in the port you want to use? (3) Is any of those computers connected to a VPN? (4) Can you access the network logs to see if there was an incoming request?

Comment: @acarlstein my pc OS is windows 11 , the other device is an Iphone.
what do you mean by "firewall setup correctly"? 
Yes, I created a rule to allow traffic in the specific port.
None of the machines are connected to VPN.
And as for the last question I am not sure, I will be glad if you can elaborate.

Comment: (1) Try to install some app in the iPhone that allows you to "ping". Three names I see when I search online are "Ping - Network Utility", "Pingify", and "Network Ping Lite". Try to see if you can ping the IP that shows in your Windows [here is how to find the IP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-in-windows-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9). (2) Also, check the IP the iPhone has. [Here is how to find it in Iphone](https://www.howtogeek.com/796854/iphone-ip-address/)